Actual nuance of 面影?

The character is looking at this friend's photos as a child and says this. The friend answer "There was also that kind of time"
What does 面影here imply?

How do you actually understand the word? Sorry but the question just looks like a simple translation request in the current form.

My reading is akin to "You resemble him/you still look like it" but I don't understand the other's answer then. "There was a time I was still like that"?

And that means you already correctly understand the basic meaning of 面影. The detailed explanation of 面影 itself won't help you...

面影 is a "trace", "hint", or "essence" of someone, and 面影ありますね means "I can see traces of you in this photo". Of course, being able to sense some hint in a childhood photo doesn't mean that a child and an adult look the same. It's not at all unnatural for him to follow up by saying "I also had such a time".
